# Pass variable to amCharts.loadfile method?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

**Situation**

I am working on a graph where a user will be able to select a value in a dropdown list and data is loaded into a graph. 
I have found a similar example on amCharts website. 
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-loading-chart-datasets/

The problem with this example is the data is "hard coded" so for each option their must be a pre built link.

**What I have done**

So far, I have got my charts working and created a controller that counts 3  statuses depending on what "Item" was passed in.

However my item_name variable is always null.

```
public ActionResult checkPriority(string item_name)
{
    decimal?[] priCount = { 0, 0, 0 };

    priCount[0] = db.vw_priCount.Where(i => i.itemDescrip == item_name&& i.itemStatus == 1).Count();
    priCount[1] = db.vw_priCount.Where(i => i.itemDescrip == item_name&& i.itemStatus == 2).Count();
    priCount[2] = db.vw_priCount.Where(i => i.itemDescrip == item_name&& i.itemStatus == 3).Count(); 


    return Json(priCount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

This is my index page code

```
 <script>



        var chart;


            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Home/checkPriority',
                    data:{
                        item_name: "Pens"
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccessBoxCountPri,
                    error: OnErrorCallPri
                });

            });

            function OnErrorCallPri(response) {
                alert('An error occured with the charts, please try again later.');
            }

            function OnSuccessBoxCountPri(priCount) {
                console.log(priCount);


                  chart = AmCharts.makeChart("pribarchartdiv", {
                    "type": "serial",
                    "theme": "none",
                    "marginRight": 70,
                    "dataProvider": [{
                        "Priority Level": "Low",
                        "cost": priCount[0],
                        "color": "#FF0F00"
                    }, {
                        "Priority Level": "Medium",
                        "cost": priCount[1],
                        "color": "#FF6600"
                    }, {
                        "Priority Level": "High",
                        "cost": priCount[2],
                        "color": "#FF9E01"
                    }, {
                        "Priority Level": "Very High",
                        "cost": priCount[3],
                        "color": "#04D215"


                    }],
                    "valueAxes": [{
                        "axisAlpha": 0,
                        "position": "left",
                        "title": "Priority"
                    }],
                    "startDuration": 1,
                    "graphs": [{
                        "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
                        "fillColorsField": "color",
                        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                        "type": "column",
                        "valueField": "cost"
                    }],
                    "chartCursor": {
                        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                        "cursorAlpha": 0,
                        "zoomable": false
                    },
                    "categoryField": "Priority Level",
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "gridPosition": "start",
                        "labelRotation": 45
                    },
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }

                });



            }



            function setDataSet(dataset_url) {

                AmCharts.loadFile("checkPriority",{}, function (data) {
                    console.log(dataset_url);//itemname in here
                    console.log(data);//0,0,0
                    chart.dataProvider = AmCharts.parseJSON(data);
                chart.validateData();
            });
        }

    </script>
    <p class="selector">
        <select onchange="setDataSet(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="Pens">Data Set #1</option>
            <option value="Chalk">Data Set #2</option>
            <option value="Books">Data Set #3</option>
        </select> &lt; Select a data set
    </p>
```

I believe this is the line `AmCharts.loadFile("checkPriority",{}, function (data) {` that I should pass my variable (which is the value of the checkbox) in. Any assistance on how I go about doing this of if it can even be done would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AmCharts.loadFile` is an AJAX method provided by the dataLoader plugin that performs a GET request. As indicated in the [documentation](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#using-data-loaders-standalone-functions), the first parameter is the URL to your endpoint, so you'll want to pass a valid URL as the first parameter.

Since your endpoint requires a POST to get the data, you're better off using your own AJAX call instead of using the loadFile method. For example:

```
function setDataSet(dataset) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/checkPriority',
    data:{
      item_name: dataset
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      chart.dataProvider = data; 
      /* or if you need to set each element individually like in your makeChart call:
      chart.dataProvider = [{
        "Priority Level": "Low",
        "cost": data[0],
        "color": "#FF0F00"
      }, {
        "Priority Level": "Medium",
        "cost": data[1],
        "color": "#FF6600"
      }, {
        "Priority Level": "High",
        "cost": data[2],
        "color": "#FF9E01"
      }, {
        "Priority Level": "Very High",
        "cost": data[3],
        "color": "#04D215"
      }];
      */
      chart.validateData();
    },
    error: OnErrorCallPri
  });
}
```